# How can I use rts function for time series TIFF using R

Tags: r, modis

I am trying to plot a time series for my TIFF stack MODIS EVI with the rts function.

I am trying to use this script but I do not know if I can use it for my TIFF stack.

```
path <- system.file("D:/Rteledetection/Pivots/MODIS", package="rts") # location of files

lst <- list.files(path=path,pattern='.asc$',full.names=TRUE) # in this line i'm usinf TIF in asc 
lst # list of raster files
```

I need some explanation if the function rts just for .asc format all for all format of raster

Can I use rts for my TIFF raster MODIS?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the help for the `rts` function you will see:

```
Usage:
      rts(x, time)

Arguments:
       x: A character vector including names of image/raster files, or
          ‘RasterStack’ or ‘RasterBrick’ object, or the name
          (character) of a raster time series file
```

So the first argument can be a list of names, or a RasterStack.